# Meaning of "owedst"

Tags: meaning, verbs, quotes, early-modern-english

> ...Not poppy, nor mandragora,
>   Nor all the drowsy syrups of the world,
>   Shall ever medicine thee to that sweet sleep
>   Which thou **owedst** yesterday.

— Shakespeare, *Othello* III.iii

I really can't find any clear definition of this word, here.
From context, all I can assume is that it means to ingest or consume?

Comment: I'd guess it's an archaic past tense of "to owe", i.e. "Which you owed yesterday"?

Comment: Well, he says `Not poppy, nor mandragora`.  
He has another quote about mandragora: `Give me to drink mandragora... that I might sleep out this great gap of time` -- Antony and Cleopatra I.v

Comment: I know Shakespearian English is considered "modern", but I guess I'm young enough that it always looks to me like another language with some of the same words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a second person past tense form of "to owe." To give a parse of the morphology:

```
owe - d   -  st
owe - past - 2sg
```

The "-d" or "-ed" is the usual past tense (and participle) marking we know and love today. The "-st" is the second person singular agreement morpheme, which we no longer have in Modern English.

As for its meaning, "owed" sort of makes sense, but this might be a more archaic use for it.

**Edit:** Here is the advanced search page for Open Search Shakespeare:
http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-advanced.php

If you select Regular Expression and search `.*edst`, you'll find a lot more examples with more easily recognizable verbs.

Comment: As this is the accepted answer, it would be good to explicitly include the apparently-more-appropriate archaic meaning which you allude to (see [cindi's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/the-definition-of-owedst/2264#2264)).

Answer (score 10):

Apparently there is an archaic sense of 'owe' meaning to possess or to own: [owe in merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/owe). The object of 'Owedst' is the sleep, which the subject enjoyed (or 'owned'), not the concoctions that he could have ingested.

Answer (score 2):

The "-st" is a verb ending that indicates second person singular. It is still present in contemporary German, for example.

Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=owe&searchmode=none):

> **owe**
>       O.E. agan (pt. ahte) "to have, own," from P.Gmc. **aiganan* "to possess" [...]. Sense of "to have to repay" began in late O.E. with the phrase *agan to geldanne* lit. "to own to yield," which was used to translate L. *debere* (earlier in O.E. this would have been *sceal* "shall"); by late 12c. the phrase had been shortened to simply *agan*, and *own* (v.) took over this word's original sense. An original Germanic preterite-present verb (cf. *can*, *dare*, *may*, etc.). New past tense form *owed* arose 15c. to replace *oughte*, which developed into *ought*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the text
http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/othello/T33.html#sd329

and nicely enough here is the explanation

http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/othello/S33.html#reenterO

> **Re-enter Othello:** As Iago speaks of
>   the corrosive effect of jealousy,
>   Othello appears with such a haunted
>   look on his face that Iago comments,
>   "I did say so. / Look where he comes!"
>   (3.3.329-330). Iago means that
>   Othello's state is proof of what Iago
>   has just been saying. It's as though
>   he is inviting us admire his
>   handiwork; just a glance at Othello
>   should be enough to prove that the
>   poison of jealousy has taken hold. As
>   Othello approaches, Iago says to him,
>   though not so Othello can hear, "Not
>   poppy, nor mandragora, / Nor all the
>   drowsy syrups of the world, / Shall
>   ever medicine thee to that sweet sleep
>   / Which thou owedst yesterday"
>   (3.3.330-333). Both "poppy" and
>   "mandragora" are opiates, very
>   powerful sleeping potions, but even
>   they won't do Othello any good. Now
>   that Iago has poisoned his mind,
>   Othello will never sleep again.